# Match two columns in two excel files and return value

Tags: excel

I want to match D column in file 1 to J column in file 2 and return the E column value in file 2 to F column in file 1. What is the best way to do it in excel?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH will do it

Comment: Thanks Soctt. Now I'm trying to figure-out this using Index/Match.

Comment: See the link provided at the top.  It will give examples.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out...